# Resolving different groups of collections

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

In the unit-test below, I'm trying to inject two different groups of a MyInterFace[] array, however it seem like I'm doing it the wrong way, since I'll get instances created of all my implementations of IMyInterface, which is rather inefficient....

```
namespace UnitTest.Interface
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {

    }
}

namespace UnitTest.ArrayGroup1
{
    public class MyInjected1 : IMyInterface
    {
        public static int Instancecount { get; set; }
        public MyInjected1()
        {
            Instancecount++;
        }

    }

    public class MyInjected2 : IMyInterface
    {
        public static int Instancecount { get; set; }
        public MyInjected2()
        {
            Instancecount++;
        }
    }
}

namespace UnitTest.ArrayGroup2
{
    public class MyInjected3 : IMyInterface
    {
        public static int Instancecount { get; set; }
        public MyInjected3()
        {
            Instancecount++;
        }
    }

    public class MyInjected4 : IMyInterface
    {
        public static int Instancecount { get; set; }
        public MyInjected4()
        {
            Instancecount++;
        }
    }
}


namespace UnitTest
{
    public class MyClass1
    {
        private IMyInterface[] collection;
        public MyClass1(IMyInterface[] group1collection)
        {
            collection = group1collection;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        private IMyInterface[] collection;
        public MyClass2(IMyInterface[] group2collection)
        {
            collection = group2collection;
        }
    }

    public class MySubResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IKernel kernel;
        public MySubResolver(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
        }
        public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
        {
            return dependency.TargetType == typeof(IMyInterface[]);
        }

        public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
        {
            IMyInterface[] res;
            if (dependency.DependencyKey == "group1collection")
                res= kernel.ResolveAll<IMyInterface>().Where(t =>
                {
                    var ns = t.GetType().Namespace;
                    return ns != null && ns.StartsWith("UnitTest.ArrayGroup1");
                }).ToArray();
            else
                res= kernel.ResolveAll<IMyInterface>().Where(t =>
                {
                    var ns = t.GetType().Namespace;
                    return ns != null && ns.StartsWith("UnitTest.ArrayGroup2");
                }).ToArray();
            return res;
        }
    }



    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var kernel = new DefaultKernel(new DefaultProxyFactory());
            kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new MySubResolver(kernel));    
            var container = new WindsorContainer(kernel, new DefaultComponentInstaller());
            container.Register(
                Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                       .BasedOn<IMyInterface>()
                       .WithServiceFirstInterface()
                       .LifestyleTransient());
            container.Register(Component.For<MyClass1>().LifeStyle.Transient);
            container.Register(Component.For<MyClass2>().LifeStyle.Transient);

            var sut=container.Resolve<MyClass1>();

            Assert.AreEqual(MyInjected1.Instancecount, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(MyInjected2.Instancecount, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(MyInjected3.Instancecount, 0);
            Assert.AreEqual(MyInjected4.Instancecount, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I call ResolveAll in my SubResolver, so I only get instances created of the classes I really need??

TIA

/Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you require using ResolveAll?  If you don't care, this will do the trick as the Resolve method of your sub-resolver.

```
    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        IMyInterface[] res;
        IHandler[] handlers;

        if (dependency.DependencyKey == "group1collection")
        {
            handlers = kernel.GetHandlers(typeof(IMyInterface)).Where(handler => handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.Namespace.StartsWith("UnitTest.ArrayGroup1")).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            handlers = kernel.GetHandlers(typeof(IMyInterface)).Where(handler => handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.Namespace.StartsWith("UnitTest.ArrayGroup2")).ToArray();
        }

        res = new IMyInterface[handlers.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = handlers[i].Resolve(context) as IMyInterface;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand the question, let me see if I can help clarify.

If ResolveAll took a predicate argument the castle folks would be in a spot where they could filter their resolution.  However, since you're just using the System.Linq extension, it doesn't have the ability to filter until the collection is created, aka resolved by castle.

[New in castle version 3](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Whats-New-In-Windsor-3&NS=Windsor) is exactly what you're looking for, the IHandlerFilter.

Comment: The problem is that instances of MyInjected3 & Myinjected4 are getting created, even though I only need MyInjected1 & MyInjected2 ... I'm my case they are simple (low cost), but in a complex case it could cost a lot to instantiate objects that are not needed. Would have expected ResolveAll<>().Where() to only instantiate the objects  that fulfill the where clause.

Comment: I only Resolve MyClass1, so I wouldn't expect instances of MyInjected3 & MyInjected4 to be instantiated...

Comment: Not quite sure how an IHandlersFilter would help... The IHandlersFilter, knows about the Type I'm trying to resolve and the possible handlers, but it doesn't seem to know about the DependencyModel (group1collection), so unless I can somehow tell ResolveAll, to use a given IHandlersFilter, then it doesn't really solve the problem.